# multi line textbox to array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to transfer values from each line of a multi line text box into either a string array or a multidimensional array.  I also have 3 multi-line text boxes which need to put into the same array. Below is one of the methods I have been trying:

```
ParkingTimes[0] = tbxtimeLimitS1.Text;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
   ParkingTimes[i] = tbxparkingTimesS1.Lines;

ParkingTimes[11] = tbxtimeLimitS2.Lines;

for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
   for (int i = 12; i <= 21; i++)
       ParkingTimes[i] = tbxparkingTimesS2.Lines;

ParkingTimes[11] = tbxtimeLimitS2.Lines[0];

for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    for (int i = 23; i <= 32; i++)
        ParkingTimes[i] = tbxparkingTimesS3.Lines;
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a List instead of a string array 
Then the AddRange method could simplify your method eliminatig the foreach loop

```
List<string> ParkingTimes = new List<string>()
ParkingTimes.Add(tbxtimeLimitS1.Text);   
ParkingTimes.AddRange(tbxparkingTimesS1.Lines);
ParkingTimes.AddRange(tbxtimeLimitS2.Lines);   
ParkingTimes.AddRange(tbxparkingTimesS2.Lines);   
ParkingTimes.AddRange(tbxtimeLimitS2.Lines);   
ParkingTimes.AddRange(tbxparkingTimesS3.Lines);
```

If your code still requires a string array it is possible to get back the array with

```
string[] myLines = ParkingTimes.ToArray();
```

An example of this `List<string>` functionality could be found on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z883w3dc%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: how do i add the line to the array in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 15):

You can simply do

```
string[] allLines = textbox.Text.Split('\n');
```

This will split each line and store the results in the appropriate index in the array.  You can then iterate over them like so:

```
foreach (string text in allLines)
{
    //do whatever with text
}
```

Comment: how do i add add the text in allLines to a string array?

Comment: allLines will be your string array. The output of textbox.Text.Split() should be an array of strings, which would then be assigned to allLines

Comment: @JackTcRebelTreble: Yes I did mean .Text.Split(), sorry.  @Nick Udell is correct: The `allLines` variable *is* the array with the strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
var totalLines = new List<String>();
totalLines.AddRange( tbxparkingTimesS1.Lines );
totalLines.AddRange( tbxparkingTimesS2.Lines );
totalLines.AddRange( tbxparkingTimesS3.Lines );
```

if you need it in an array instead of a list, then call:

```
var array = totalLines.ToArray();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You! - just testing it out now

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
string[] textArray = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] split = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
```

> or you can also use:

```
int srlno=10;
string[] split = new string[srlno];
foreach(string x in textBox1.Lines)
{
     split = (split ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()).Concat(new[] { x }).ToArray();
}
```